# [papaparse]Parse Error handler

Tags: javascript, error-handling, papaparse

I am having trouble getting the Papa error object into my error handler. My parse suddenly stopped working and I just want to work out why / what changed! I use the following code to parse it:

`Papa.parse(path, {download: true, header: true, complete: ListifyCSVData, error: CSVParseError});`

My CSVParseError function gets called. But the error object is undefined:

```
CSVParseError = function(err, file){
alert("Unable to process CSV file, please verify the file can be accessed and try again. Error reason was: " + err.code);
```

}

Does anyone have any tips for what might be wrong here please?

Thank you for your help.

Glen

Comment: Is `err` undefined, or is `err.code` undefined, on an otherwise perfectly fine `err` object that might contain other information?

Comment: hi James, it was err that was undefined. However, it is working again today with no changes! I can only assume it was some environmental issue but I cant recreate it now. Thanks for taking the time to respond.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that there is a bug in the library, although I'm only guessing at this point.

Can you open an issue on GitHub and also show the exact error message you're getting? If it's a bug in Papa Parse we definitely want to fix it.

Comment: hi Matt, as above, I cant recreate the issue now. if I manage to I'll try and get a jsFiddle going and report the issue. Thank you for your support.